Edit GeoParquet layer on QGIS
I have a geometry which is GeoParquet format. I want to edit it in QGIS , however, I can't toggle the edit mode:

Is there any way I can edit the layer without converting it to other format?
It is very heavy and if I'm not using GeoParquet it takes forever to load.

As far as I know this is not possible. A GeoParquet file needs to be written in one go, you cannot make small changes in only part of it... which is why it cannot be edited.
For large files I also would not expect GeoParquet to be faster than most typical formats for most uses as it doesn't support a (proper) spatial index. Just for some very specific uses, like reading the entire file in memory in one go, it might be faster.
Have you tried using e.g. Geopackage, the default file format used in QGIS?

yes, but it is still very heavy

With "heavy" you mean taking more diskspace or ?

it takes long time to load, the file is very large, therefore editing the layer takes long time as well @Pieter

Odd. When you are zoomed in like you show in the screenshot e.g. Geopackage should be fast, +- regardless of the size of the file. Unless... the file containes one (or a few) huge multipolygons. Would it be a problem to "explode"/"Multipart-to-singlepart" the file?
